# How to make bash -x work on environmental functions but not only scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, debugging, stderr

I have been able to use set -x to make scripts working in more verbose way. But I couldn't make it work in the same way for my functions.

By setting script like this, I can dump the debug lines to logs:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -x
```

But if I want to call function from shell instead call scripts, it doesn't work anymore:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -x
# defined in my test.sh file
hello(){
set -x
echo 'helloWorld'
}
hello
```

When I call the function and dump output to logs, the debug info only print out but not writing to logs:

```sh
. test.sh
hello > test.log
```

Is there something apparently wrong or missing here?

Comment: Redirect **`stderr`** (file handle 2) instead: `hello 2> test.log`

Comment: Thank you! so that debug messages are dumped from 2. I used 1>test.log 2>&1 perfectly resolved the issue. if you answer my question I'll accept it.